# Как закрыть от индексации саму страницу, но не ссылки на ней?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Вкратце. Есть Инт-магаз, и я решил сделать карту сайта, где будут ссылки не только на категории товаров, но и по разным фильтрам в категориях.

Т.е будет ссылка на "Кроссовки", потом ссылка на "Мужские кроссовки", далее на "Мужские красные кроссовки" и так далее.

В общем итоге более млн разных вариаций.

И т.к все ссылки в одну страницу не впихнуть, сделал пагинацию на странице "карта сайта".

**И у меня 2 вопроса.**
Стоит ли вообще на сайте размещать такую огромную "Карта сайта"? Не скажется ли плохо это на индексации более важных страниц?

И как убрать из индексации поисковиков сами страницы этой карты, а то в добавок ко всем этим ссылкам еще и будут индексироваться все страницы карты. Или достаточно указать canonical?

Answer (score 0):

Это делается стандартно.
Добавив эту разметку в исходный код страницы, вы предотвратите индексацию страницы, в то время как все ссылки на странице все еще могут быть просканированы:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

Comment: Ну а сама затея создания страницы с таким огромным количеством ссылок хорошая? или лучше от нее отказаться?

Comment: Давайте по порядку: "создать страницу, чтобы на ней было огромное количество ссылок, но чтобы на нее никто не заходил бы, так как не хотим индексировать и видеть ее в выдаче поисковиков, а только хотим, чтобы поисковики бы индексировали ссылки, которые на ней размещены". Если это вся затея, то я скажу вам, что для таких целей существует sitemap.xml, в которых и размещаются ссылки для индексации. Но скажу вам больше:  даже sitemap.xml не нужен, если те ссылки доступны на других страницах; поисковикам не требуется наличие каких-то "скрытых" страниц с ссылками навигации - проиндексируют и так.